# Uber SDK in swift 3 and xcode 8 compatible

Tags: ios, swift3, uber-api

I have upgraded my Xcode to version 8.0. When i tried to build my app its showing lots of errors in Uber files, do you have uber iOS SDKs that support swift 3. I have integrated Uber SDK using cocoa pods. I tried to update pods using 'pod update' but its of no use.

Thanks,

Comment: it seems they are currently [migrating to swift 3](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/60), so there is no support yet

Comment: Ok, Thank you @serg_zhd

Answer (score 2):

The Uber Rides iOS SDK does not support Swift 3 yet. We have an experimental branch, but it is not stable yet.

Comment: I have also tried to integrate with xcode 8.2 and swift 3.0 but no luck..

Comment: We currently support swift 2.3 in the latest sdk: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk

Comment: do you have any idea, when swift 3.0 sdk will be available?

Comment: We do not have an exact eta at this time. You can follow the github issue for updates: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/60

Answer (score 1):

Replace

pod 'UberRides'

with

pod 'UberRides', :git => 'https://github.com/long/rides-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'swift-3-dev’

This is a working solution until there is an official Swift 3 edition in master